# Copying line by line from one text file to another using Python

Tags: python

I'm new in Python and in programming in general, I'm trying to create an srt file from a text file(that contains the subtitles )

This is the code I have:

```
  with open("in3.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
   # lines = [l for l in lines]
    with open("out.txt", "w") as f1:
        for x in range(0, 7):
            y = x*10
            f1.write("\n00:01:"+str(y)+"\n")
            f1.writelines(lines)
```

And this is what I get:

`00:01:0
This is 1st line
This is 2nd line
This is 3rd line
This is 4th line
This is 5th line
00:01:10
This is 1st line
This is 2nd line
This is 3rd line
This is 4th line
This is 5th line
00:01:20
This is 1st line
This is 2nd line
This is 3rd line
This is 4th line
This is 5th line
...`

However, the outcome desired is this:

`00:01:0
This is 1st line
00:01:10
This is 2nd line
00:01:20
This is 3rd line
00:01:30
This is 4th line`

in3.txt contains:

```
This is 1st line
This is 2nd line
This is 3rd line
This is 4th line
This is 5th line
```

Any help will be appreciated :)
Thank you

Comment: Try indenting your example code by four spaces so that it will be formatted as a code block - it's pretty hard to read as it is now

Comment: You probably want to write the index of the line that you're writing in the line `f1.write("\n00:01:"+str(y)+"\n")`.

Comment: could you explain how the contents of "in3.txt" look

Comment: Change `f1.writelines(lines) ` to `f1.writelines(lines[x]))`

Comment: Or remove the `readlines()` completely and just do `f1.write(f.readline())` or even better iterate over `for x, line in enumerate(f):` and then `f1.write(line)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is solution using `enumerate`:

```
with open("in3.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    with open("out.txt", "w") as f1:
        for x, line in enumerate(lines): # Changed to enumerate as per recommendation
            y = x*10
            f1.write("\n00:01:"+str(y)+"\n")
            f1.write(line)
```

will produce following output:

```
00:01:0
This is 1st line

00:01:10
This is 2nd line

00:01:20
This is 3rd line

00:01:30
This is 4th line

00:01:40
This is 5th line
```

Image added for clarification:

[image]

Comment: please use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), it hurts my eyes to see `zip(range(...), iterable)`

Comment: I still have the same output, didn't get the output you have :(

Comment: @user3600078 are you absolutely sure that you **ran** this program and then **closed and reopened** `out.txt` and it was still the same? If you had left it open in notepad it wouldn't have refreshed the new content.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the index of `lines`:

```
with open("in3.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    with open("out.txt", "w") as f1:
        for x in range(0, 7):
            y = x*10
            f1.write("\n00:01:"+str(y)+"\n")
            f1.write(lines[x]) # Changed f1.writelines(lines) to f1.write(lines[x]))
```

Comment: I think you just want `f1.write(lines[x])` instead of `writelines`

Answer (score 0):

Your f1.writelines(lines) is happening INSIDE the loop. So every time you go round the loop, you're writing the whole of `lines`.

This is difficult to debug without knowing what's in `in3.txt` too.

Comment: this should just be a comment.

Comment: @Radan I'd disagree since it does explain why the OP is getting the result they are, however this answer could be greatly improved with some steps to fix the issue.